# Change background color of message after read

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a button attached to mat-menu, which when clicked has red background.

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matmenunotification)

```
.list-item.error {
  background-color:#FCE8FF;
}
```

But instead I want to change the color after the button is clicked more than two times to:

```
list-item.seen {
  background-color: lightgray;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

These are the two classes which can drive that functionality:

```
[class.seen]="!seenMe"                      
[class.error]="true"
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-icon-button
(click)="openMe()"
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="notify">
  <mat-icon>
    warning
  </mat-icon> Click Me
</button>
<mat-menu #notify="matMenu" class="mat-menu-notify">
  <mat-dialog-content (click)="stayOpen($event);">
    <mat-list >
      <div >
        <mat-list-item [class.seen]="!seenMe"                      
                       [class.error]="true"
                       class="list-item">
            <span class="message">
              I was here
            </span>
        </mat-list-item>
      </div>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-dialog-content>
</mat-menu>
```

TS:

```
notSeenYet = true;

  get seenMe(): boolean|undefined {
    return this.notSeenYet;
    console.log(this.notSeenYet);
  }

  openMe(): boolean{
    return this.notSeenYet = false;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background after double click?

Comment: how can you check message read is complete?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, so there is a boolean value coming from the service which tells if that message is read or not, currently I am using just direct boolean values which can replicate the scenario

Comment: @Bob Actually unable to understand your requirement! Can you please explain in terms of Expected or current output?

Comment: @upinderkumar I have a service returning the boolean values which determines whether the message is read or not, I am just struggling with the logic to handle that boolean values, so when true - background should be red and if false should be gray

Comment: @Bob Check the posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly:

Use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

HTML:

```
[ngClass]="notSeenYet ? 'error' : 'seen'"
```

CSS:

```
.error{
  // Other CSS
  background-color: red;
}

.seen{
  // Other CSS
  background-color: gray;
}
```

so if `notSeenYet` variable is true then it will apply the `error` CSS class otherwise seen CSS class.

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matmenunotification-5ksmwy) is a sample demo.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired behavior is not very clear, but as I understood this is what you want?

```
<mat-list-item [class.seen]="seenMe" [class.error]="presses>2" class="list-item">
   <span class="message">
      I was here
   </span>
</mat-list-item>
```

TS

```
openMe(): boolean {
    this.presses++;
    return this.notSeenYet = false;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matmenunotification-6kum56?file=src/app/app.component.html)